# Hot to solve "Error in munmap(): Cannot allocate memory" in Memgraph

Tags: memgraphdb

On my Ubuntu server I run Memgraph. I just got a bunch of errors

```
11/21/2023
07:15:31 PM
<jemalloc>: Error in munmap(): Cannot allocate memory
11/21/2023
07:15:32 PM
<jemalloc>: Error in munmap(): Cannot allocate memory
11/21/2023
07:15:33 PM
<jemalloc>: Error in munmap(): Cannot allocate memory
11/21/2023
07:15:34 PM
<jemalloc>: Error in munmap(): Cannot allocate memory
11/21/2023
07:15:35 PM
<jemalloc>: Error in munmap(): Cannot allocate memory
11/21/2023
```

I should have enough RAM, so what could be the reason for this? I'm not sure if it is related to [this GiHub issue](https://github.com/memgraph/memgraph/pull/1471), but the new version of Memgraph is not out yet so I can't test.

Comment: Not sure if you have resolved this, but I am still getting in memgraph 2.13

Comment: @Avocado I posted an answer, hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will notice the memgraph startup message

> Max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count 65530 is too low, increase
> to at least 262144

Run `sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144` to increase the max virtual map count